# Kibana displaying wrong data

Tags: php, elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-5

So i'm currently working on some temperature logging. I've set up a php-script that will pump data directly in elasticsearch. So far, so good.

For displaying that data i've used Kibana 5. But Kibana is somehow displaying not the right data :(.

Here is an example:
The elasticsearch dump:

```
  {
    "_index": "temp",
    "_type": "sensor_data",
    "_id": "AVw2t2C8BalsJaItPPk5",
    "_score": null,
    "_source": {
      "temp01": 20.25,
      "temp02": 21.375,
      "temp03": 21.875,
      "temp04": 23.875,
      "temp05": 17.625,
      "timestamp": 1495566606
    },
    "sort": [
      1495566606000
    ]
  },
  {
    "_index": "temp",
    "_type": "sensor_data",
    "_id": "AVw2tnfsBalsJaItPPk3",
    "_score": null,
    "_source": {
      "temp01": 20.312,
      "temp02": 21.375,
      "temp03": 21.875,
      "temp04": 23.875,
      "temp05": 17.687,
      "timestamp": 1495566546
    },
    "sort": [
      1495566546000
    ]
  }
```

In Kibana it looks like this: [Kibana](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sby94.png)

The temp01 graph is fine (and all other ones) except for the temp03 one.

And here are the index patterns: [index patterns in Kibana](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPDcI.png)

Can someone help me?
Thanks :)

Comment: So i found the problem. I dont know why, but elasticsearch tried to save temp03 as a long and not as a float. I changed it to float and it worked like it should. But i can't explain why it shows in the dump as a float...